# How to resume a suspended Camel consumer

Tags: apache-camel

I created a [RoutePolicy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-policy.html) that suspends a consumer when a configurable number of errors occurred in the route.

Before I suspend the consumer I want to **make sure it will be resumed** after a configurable amount of time (for example 30 minutes after suspension).

What is the best way to achieve this?

- I tried to use the `onExchangeBegin` method of the RoutePolicy. But in a test I found that it is no more executed when the route is suspended (as I assumed).
- I tried to create a [SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/scheduledroutepolicy.html) before suspending the route but I didn't found a way to register this new Bean in the Camel context (backed by Spring).
- Therefore I currently create a [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) that sends a message to [Camel Control Bus](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/controlbus-component.html) to resume the route. That works, but feels a bit of alien since Camel does not know about such resume tasks.
- Is there another, more "Camel native" way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Before you suspend the consumer, you can create a dummy file.

Have another route polling for the dummy file with a filter to check if it was created 30 minutes prior. Something like:

```
from("file:dummyLocation?include=.dummy&delete=true&filter=#filterFileOlderThanThirtyMins)
.to("controlbus:route?routeId=suspendedRoute&action=start")
```

This is just off the top of my head, though!

Comment: I consider the filesystem as "unreliable" in the sense that it is a shared storage. Files could accidentally be deleted by other processes, files could become blocked etc. But thanks a lot for the very creative idea!

Comment: Yeah. Understood. Okay, how about this. Just before you suspend the consumer, you start another route, with a delay of 30 minutes. At the end of the delay, you use controlbus to start your suspended route. Once the route is restarted, stop the timer route!

Comment: You are full of ideas! :-) However, a RoutePolicy can be applied to any number of routes. So my policy would have to create and manage (start/stop) a TimerRoute for every suspendable route. Even worse: with a RoutePolicyFactory I can apply the policy to ALL routes in the context. So this would become a recursion because my policy creates TimerRoutes to whom the policy is applied by the factory. Through the application of the policy TimerRoutes for the TimerRoutes are created ... and so on.